# Showing the users' username on screen. Getting 'Undefined Index' error

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Okay, so I'm trying to display the users first name as a greeting message on index.php like, 'Hello, (users first name), but im pretty new to all this php stuff so i really cant figure out how to do this. I tried to follow a short tutorial, but whenever i try to print the first name with 'print $_POST['first_name'] i get a undefined index error.... Might be a stupid question, but i just cant figure it out.

Here's my db_connect.php if it matters at all:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "Byt til Nyt";
$ms = mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $pass);
if ( !$ms )
{
echo "Could not connect to database.";
}

mysql_select_db("$db");

?>
```

Here's a short version of my register.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Register</title>
<?php
include('includes/db_connect.php');
if (@$_GET["op"] == "reg") {
    $bInputFlag = false;
    foreach ($_POST as $field) {
        if ($field == "") {
            $bInputFlag = false;
        } else {
            $bInputFlag = true;
        }
    }
    if ($bInputFlag == false) {
        die("Der opstod et problem med dine oplysninger. Gå tilbage og prøv igen.");
    }
    $q = "INSERT INTO 'users' ('first_name','last_name','email','username','password')" . "VALUES ('" . $_POST["username"] . "'," . "PASSWORD ('" . $_POST["password"] . "')," . "'" . $_POST["email"] . "')";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    if (!mysql_insert_id()) {
        die("Der opstod en fejl. Du er ikke blevet tilføjet til databasen.");
    } else {
        Header("Location: register.php?op=thanks");
    }
} elseif (@$_GET["op"] == "thanks") {
    echo "<h2>Tak fordi du registrerede!</h2>";
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="includes/verify.php" name="register">
//recaptcha script here
<label>First name</label>
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Your first name" required><br>
<label>Last name</label>
<input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Your last name" required><br>
//some more input fields and stuff
```

And here's a short version of my index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("includes/functions.php");
include("includes/db_connect.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="dk">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<head>
<title>
Byt til Brugt
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body background="http://i.imgur.com/urLzQr5.jpg" bgcolor="navy">
<div class="menu">
<p>Velkommen, <?php if (isset($username)) {
print $_POST['first_name'];
}
?>
</p>
```

So, what is the problem?? :/ Any help would be VERY appreciated, I've been trying to fix this for 2 days now.... Just say if you need my login.php or anything else (: Thanks a lot! And sorry for my bad English..

Comment: The problem is that you are using single quotes to delimit column and table names.  This is a typographic error and I'm voting to close.  Only use single quotes for date and string constants.

Comment: Still getting the same error after fixing that...

Comment: . . Edit your question and print out `$q`.  You seem to be supplying more columns in the `insert` than values in the `values` clause.

Comment: you mentioned form action="include/verify.php" but why do you executed your function inside register.php and also using header location Header("Location: register.php?op=thanks");now my question is from which page you getting $_POST[first_name];

Comment: If you're new to PHP then you should use a newer tutorial. Those mysql_* functions like [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) are deprecated. It would be best if you avoid them from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST['first_name']
```

is probably not set, try

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
print $_POST['first_name'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the user POSTing to your index page, therefor the $_POST variable is empty when you try to access it.

Your register form posts to includes/verify.php

The variable $_POST is only populated for you if the user submits a form using the POST method. So you should NEVER expect it to contain data, always check it first (!empty($_POST) at the least).

What you are probably intending to do is retrieve the name from the database using their username. (Probably stored in the session?)
Once you have populated the variable then you simply echo out that variable when you need it and you will get the first name they entered when signing up.

Additionally, your signup page won't work as intended for the same reason. You are posting to includes/verify.php and judging from your code it looks like your verify page redirects the user back to register.php?op=reg which means you just lost all of your POST data unless you are using javascript to post back to register.php?op=reg (but that isn't needed)

Also, your MySQL is wrong. You are trying to insert into 5 fields

```
'first_name','last_name','email','username','password'
```

and you are only passing 3 values

```
'username', 'password', 'email'
```

You should be passing 5 values and the order should match the column list. If you set a default value for username and password then this might not cause a MySQL error but your data will not match up to the intended field.
(Username into first_name, password into last_name, email into email, nothing in username, nothing in password)

You mention that you are following a tutorial, so perhaps it's best to just look for another tutorial. Maybe one that is a little more updated considering you should avoid using mysql_connect or mysql_pconnect as a database method.